# ews cannot find KDC for realm

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, raspberry-pi, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to get the following c# code using .net core to run on a raspberry pi, the code works fine on windows and does exactly what I want it to do. But on the pi it gives me a strange exception involving kerberos. I have used this pi to run other .net core programs in the past.

My code is:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

namespace Test
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)

    {
            // Create the binding to ews
            ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
            // Set the credentials for the user
            service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("user@email.com", "password");
            // Set the URL
            service.Url = new Uri("https://email.com/ews/Exchange.asmx");
            // Create a bew email
            EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(service);
            // Set the recipiant to an email
            email.ToRecipients.Add("user@email.com");
            // Set the subject
            email.Subject = "HelloWorld";
            // Set the body
            email.Body = new MessageBody("This is the first email I've sent by using the EWS Managed API.");
            email.Send();
    }
}
}
```

However when I use dotnet core to publish it to linux-arm and then run it on the pi I get the following exception

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: GSSAPI operation failed with error - An invalid status code was supplied (Cannot find KDC for realm "email.com").
      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
      at 
 Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsHttpWebRequest.Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.IEwsHttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
  at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest request)
  at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(IEwsHttpWebRequest& request)
  at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
  at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.InternalCreateItems(IEnumerable`1 items, FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1 sendInvitationsMode, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandling)
  at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item.InternalCreate(FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1 sendInvitationsMode)
  at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage.InternalSend(FolderId parentFolderId, MessageDisposition messageDisposition)
  at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage.Send()
  at Test.Program.Main(String[] args) in V:\visual studio stuff\Test\Test\Test\Program.cs:line 23
```

Any help would be great

Comment: Thought it might be because I'm an idiot and didn't install dotnet core runtime on the pi ... it wasn't that. Anyone have anything?

Answer (score 0):

If you need GSSApi, you should install `gss-ntlmssp` which is package for Kerberos plugin. If that does not resolve, please have a look at this [GitHb Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/28961) which seems yours.